# Jenkins's builds are blocked "Option code: 65002"

Tags: java, jenkins, hudson

My jenkins can't build our project , here's the logs :

```
Jenkins is fully up and running
déc. 02, 2014 12:34:35 PM Infos hudson.triggers.SCMTrigger$Runner run
SCM changes detected in ADRIA_LIVE_BUILD. Triggering  #2487
déc. 02, 2014 12:37:02 PM Avertissement javax.jmdns.impl.DNSIncoming readAnswer
There was an OPT answer. Not currently handled. Option code: 65002 data: 38F74FF84C6CD8A3
déc. 02, 2014 12:37:16 PM Avertissement javax.jmdns.impl.DNSIncoming readAnswer
There was an OPT answer. Not currently handled. Option code: 65002 data: 38F74FF84C6CD8A3
déc. 02, 2014 12:45:24 PM Avertissement javax.jmdns.impl.DNSIncoming readAnswer
There was an OPT answer. Not currently handled. Option code: 65002 data: 38F74FF84C6CD8A3
déc. 02, 2014 12:46:34 PM Infos hudson.triggers.SCMTrigger$Runner run
SCM changes detected in ADRIA_LIVE_BUILD. Triggering  #2487
déc. 02, 2014 12:52:34 PM Infos hudson.triggers.SCMTrigger$Runner run
SCM changes detected in ADRIA_LIVE_BUILD. Triggering  #2487
déc. 02, 2014 12:56:15 PM Avertissement javax.jmdns.impl.DNSIncoming readAnswer
There was an OPT answer. Not currently handled. Option code: 65002 data: 38F74FF84C6CD8A3
déc. 02, 2014 2:53:53 PM Avertissement javax.jmdns.impl.DNSIncoming readAnswer
There was an OPT answer. Not currently handled. Option code: 65002 data: 2A965E49808B6AAD
déc. 02, 2014 2:54:45 PM Avertissement javax.jmdns.impl.DNSIncoming readAnswer
There was an OPT answer. Not currently handled. Option code: 65002 data: 2A965E49808B6AAD
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Yep getting the same behind a proxy Feb 25, 2015 6:28:49 PM javax.jmdns.impl.DNSIncoming readAnswer
WARNING: There was an OPT answer. Not currently handled. Option code: 65002 data: 987910A362F4B747

Comment: I added nginx on top of Jenkins and my issue got resolved.

Answer (score 3):

this seems to only happen on MacOS.
the problem is in jmDNS library: https://github.com/openhab/jmdns/issues/12

the specific bug filed against Jenkins is https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-25369

it has since been fixed in the library source code (https://github.com/openhab/jmdns/pull/16/files , February 2015)
but it is not included in the current Jenkins (as of July 2015).

as a workaround, you can start Jenkins like this:

```
java -Dhudson.DNSMultiCast.disabled=true -jar jenkins.war
```